# Iterate through IEnumerable Model without loop - ASP.NET-MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.beginform

I have strongly typed IEnumerable of two records which I am passing to view from controller. I always have maximum two records. I need to print these two record in separate form i.e. HTML beginform.

My question is how I can print IEnumerable Model data without using @for or @foreach loop??? Can you use some kind of index to read object in model and its data based on index???

### Get data from record

```
public List<EmergencyContact> GetEmergencyContactByStudentID(int _studentID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _uow = new StudentProfile_UnitOfWork())
            {
                var _record = (from _emergencyContact in _uow.EmergencyContact_Repository.GetAll()
                               join _student in _uow.Student_Repository.GetAll() on _emergencyContact.StudentID equals _student.StudentID
                               where _emergencyContact.StudentID == _studentID 
                               select _emergencyContact).ToList();

                return _record;
            }
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

### Controller

```
 public ActionResult EditEmergencyContact()
    {
       int _studentEntityID = 0;

        _studentEntityID = _studentProfileServices.GetStudentIDByIdentityUserID(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        List<EmergencyContact> _emergencyContactModel = new List<EmergencyContact>();

        _emergencyContactModel = _studentProfileServices.GetEmergencyContactByStudentID(_stu


  return PartialView("EditEmergencyContact_Partial", _emergencyContactModel);

    }
```

### View

```
@model IEnumerable<App.DAL.Model.EmergencyContact>
.............//other code

 @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => model.NameOfContact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

above line @html.editorFor give error; refer to screenshot as below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it by it's Index if you use a `List`:

```
@model List<App.DAL.Model.EmergencyContact>
.............//other code

 @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => model[0].NameOfContact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

But since you are now accessing the object by it's index I would always recommend checking to see if it's `null` first, even know you say you will always have 2 items in the collection, it doesn't do any harm checking.

**Update**

You can check if it is null by doing the following in a Razer view:

```
@if(Model[0] != null) 
{
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => model[0].NameOfContact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}
```

Comment: I can ensure to check this on server-side i.e. controller but how can i check null reference in razor view?